# Android: Setting variables from other classes

Tags: android

I have been trying to find a way to set variables for one class *while* in another class withous changing intents. Maybe I'm searching the wrong things, maybe I'm over complicating this, I don't know.

Basically, what I am doing at the moment is getting the listView item that is selected, checking its index value, and chaning a variable or two(from a different class) based on the choice.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
            theGame settings = null;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    settings.baseWave = 10;
                    settings.baseRate = 5;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    settings.baseWave = 20;
                    settings.baseRate = 10;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    settings.baseWave = 30;
                    settings.baseRate = 15;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

"theGame" is my outside class and "baseWave" and "baseRate" are the corrisponding varriables. Obviously, what I am doing here is not working for me. Im fairly new at all of this so be gentle.

Thank you for any help you can offer, it is much appreciated :)

~TG

Comment: Extend the application, `MyApp extends Application` and store the variable there (or in classes referenced there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nice that it struck you that you may have a bad design, but it should also have struck you that you don't know Java, that you're having this problem because you don't know Java, and that a good Java book would help you.

Well, this is the shortest path to getting this attempt of yours working: have theGame store a reference to itself in a static member; use the static member in your code.

That is,

```
class TheGame {
  public static TheGame theGame = null;
  TheGame() {
    theGame = this;
  }
}
```

And elsewhere: `TheGame.theGame.baseWave = 10 * (position + 1);`

Or you may need it put this way:

```
public class TheGame extends Activity {
  public static TheGame theGame = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    theGame = this;
  }
}
```

A good Java book would describe this sort of thing to you, give you a name for it, and warn you away from it.

Comment: Thanks A lot! this is exactly what I was looking for. I am deff. looking into buying a good book(as I only know enough java to scrape by in most cases). Do you have any reccomendations? Thanks a lot! ~TG